# Fill row with TextField?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am test Flutter UI [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter/#4) and find issue.

In composing messages field `TextField` is not expand to fill `Row`. So when user try tap on message area there is space above and under `TextField` which not trigger `TextField`. (so no open keyboard)

Try the code and tap little bit under divider. It not trigger `TextField`:

```
Widget _buildTextComposer() {
  return new IconTheme(                                            //new
    data: new IconThemeData(color: Theme.of(context).accentColor), //new
    child: new Container(                                     //modified
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
      child: new Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Flexible(
            child: new TextField(
              controller: _textController,
              onSubmitted: _handleSubmitted,
              decoration: new InputDecoration.collapsed(
                hintText: "Send a message"),
            ),
          ),
          new Container(
            margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4.0),
            child: new IconButton(
              icon: new Icon(Icons.send),
              onPressed: () => _handleSubmitted(_textController.text)),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),                                                             //new
  );
}
```

How to expand `TextField` so not have this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I think the reason is

```
InputDecoration.collapsed(hintText: "Send a message")
```

Your problem should get solved if you change it to

```
InputDecoration(hintText: "Send a message")
```

Edit: When you remove the collapsed constructor you will have to set border to none explicitly like this in order to not have the underline

```
InputDecoration(border: InputBorder.none)
```

Edit: This sample code demostrates the results;

```
Widget _buildTextComposer(BuildContext context) {
    return new IconTheme(
      //new
      data: new IconThemeData(color: Theme.of(context).accentColor), //new
      child: new Container(
        //modified
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
        child: new Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Expanded(
              child: new TextField(
                controller: _textController,
                onSubmitted: (s) {},
                decoration:
                    new InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Send a message", 
                      fillColor: Colors.green,
                      filled: true,
                      border: InputBorder.none),
              ),
            ),
            new Container(
              margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4.0),
              child: new IconButton(
                  icon: new Icon(Icons.send),
                  onPressed: () {}),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ), //new
    );
  }
```

This code provides this result:

[image: Screenshot]

The reason for the space on top is the height of the row is larger than your textfield and unfortunately at the time of writing this textfields don't expand vertically and they determine their height depending on their max line count.

Finally there is an open issue in flutter github related to this problem

[Allow multiline TextField to expand vertically to fit container #21943](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/21943)

Comment: Thanks for reply! I have test you answer but it only work for bottom of TextField. It still not stretch TextField to cover top border. Try tap just under message area top divider. It not trigger TextField.

Comment: @FlutterFirebase updated the answer for more clarification

Comment: Thanks! I understand. So problem is textfield not expand vertical. But why there is no problem with expand to bottom or to side?

Comment: Expanding horizontaly is not an issue for textfield. But vertically it seems it's bound to number of lines. I don't understand what you mean by bottom. If you change the background color of the row you can see there is equal space at the bottom too.

Comment: I was think there was no space at bottom. I not notice there is also space at bottom. In message area only notice at top.